# How to make the node progress bar not duplicate itself when bar.tick is called

Tags: node.js, terminal, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I am using the `progress` package to create a progress bar.

Here is my code:

```
bar = new ProgressBar('fetching :bar :current/:total :percent \n :currentItem \n :blocked \n Fetched: :fetched \n Queued: :queued', { total: numRequests });

bar.tick(0, {
    currentItem: `Currently Fetching Text`,
    blocked: 'Blocked text',
    fetched: 'Fecched Text',
    queued: 'Queued Text',
});
```

In other applications, I see a progress bar on the bottom that updates the text but does not create a new entry in the terminal (ex: Yarn's Install Bar). However, with `progress` I get a new message every time I call `bar.tick`. Is it possible using `progress` to just have one bar message?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great solution (causes the screen to flicker...) but there's a clear screen `console.log`

```
  console.log('\x1Bc');
```

Just put it before the `bar.tick`